# Exporting multiple files from angular library from single export

Tags: angular, wildcard, angular-library

I have a library with a `models` directory that needs to be exported. Is there a way to export them without having to use the syntax `export * from './path'` in the public-api.ts for each and every model? I was thinking maybe a wildcard

```
export * from './path/*.ts'
```

hoping it would make all models in that directory available for exporting from a single export.

Is there a way to do this, or am I left to type out the export for each model?

Comment: Had a same question. Just curious did you find any solution for this?